# Regex match checksum with or without dashes

Tags: regex, pcre

To match a dash-less checksum I can do something like:

```
\b[0-9a-z]{32}\b
```

However, I'm seeing some checksums that also have dashes, such as:

```
d3bd55bf-062f-473b-9417-935f62c4c98a
```

While this is probably a fixed size, 8, then 4, then 4, then 4, then 12, I was wondering if I could do a regex where the number of non-dash digits **adds up to** 32. I think the answer is no, but hopefully some regex wizard can come up with something.

Here is a starting point for some sample inputs: https://regex101.com/r/K0IMKe/1.

Comment: Try `\b(?:[0-9a-z]-?){32}\b`. Or, `\b[0-9a-z](?:-?[0-9a-z]){31}\b` if there can be no `-` at the end.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, can you explain how that works in an answer?

Comment: Or if there can be 0 - 4 dashes, you can assert 32 - 36 chars `^(?=[a-z0-9-]{32,36}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$` https://regex101.com/r/JM3EP6/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\b[0-9a-z](?:-?[0-9a-z]){31}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kuaPzC/1).

It matches

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[0-9a-z]` - a digit or a lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?:-?[0-9a-z]){31}` - thirty-one repetitions of an optional `-` followed with a single digit or a lowercase ASCII letter
- `\b` - a word boundary.

If you do not mind having a trailing `-` if there is a word char after it, at the end of a match, you may also use

```
\b(?:[0-9a-z]-?){32}\b
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kuaPzC/2). Here, `(?:[0-9a-z]-?){32}` will match thirty-two repetitions of a digit or lowercase ASCII letter followed with an optional hyphen.

Comment: great, thanks so much for the clear explanation. Out of curiosity, other than "practice", how would you suggest improving my regex skills?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 Through practice, you will learn how to quickly choose the best pattern for each situation. To actually learn, you need to study separate cases and the their solutions. You may learn a lot at rexegg.com and regular-expressions.info.

Answer (score 1):

If there can be multiple dashes, you can assert 32 to 36 chars using a positive lookahead.

```
^(?=[a-z0-9-]{32,36}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[a-z0-9-]{32,36}$)` Positive lookahead, assert what is at the right is 32 - 36 repetitions of the listed characters
- `[a-z0-9]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `-[a-z0-9]+` Match a `-` followed by 1+ times any of the listed (the string can not end with a hyphen)
- `)*` Close the group and match 0+ times to also match the string without dashes
- `$`  End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JM3EP6/1)

If you want to limit the amount of dashes to 0 -4 times, you can change the quantifier `*` to `{0,4}+`

```
^(?=[a-z0-9-]{32,36}$)[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+){0,4}+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/57ycOV/1)